# React.js - мультидоменность

Tags: javascript, reactjs, роутинг

Возможно ли в React.js сделать роутинг с поддоменами? Например, пользователь заходит на auth.domen.com, после чего ему доступен переход на несколько других поддоменов, например brokers.domen.com или sales.domen.com, и все это в рамках одного приложения.

Answer (score 6):

В рамках одного приложения нельзя - History Api не позволит. https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/History_API

> ...Новый URL должен идти на тот же домен, протокол и порт, иначе, pushState() будет ругаться...

Разбивай SPA на несколько частей.

Comment: но в апаче же легко сделать так что бы со всех поддоменов шли запросі на лдин файл. Как разбивать? Надо где то сохранить токен

Comment: @JonnyManowar храни cookies на `.domain.com`. Обрати внимание, что впереди точка, так cookies будут расшариваться между поддоменами.

Comment: костыльный вариант. Есть множество сайтов на которых десятки поддоменов, и домены создаются динамически. Например, для разных языков или для пользователей, типа username.domen.com, тут уж точно не создают отдельніе приложухи

Comment: @JonnyManowar можно сделать один SPA и сделать предварительную фильтрацию по домену. Только нельзя сделать так, чтобы на одной странице менялись домены / поддомены, перемещение между ними только по `<a>`, без прерывания их работы. А так можно, почему нет. Только вот лучше разбить SPA на несколько категорий. К примеру, авторизация/регистрация, панель пользователя, админка. И выставлять на них права доступа. А абсолютно цельный мультидоменный SPA сделать не получится.